# How do I deal with problems during training testing with container that I supply scripts in folder train?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I am working on updating existing working example of sentiment pytorch sagemaker. I trained the model OK with this:

```
from sagemaker.pytorch import PyTorch

estimator = PyTorch(entry_point="train.py",
                source_dir="./train",
                role=role,
                framework_version='1.6.0',
                py_version='py3',                    
                instance_count=1,
                instance_type='ml.p2.xlarge',
                hyperparameters={
                    'epochs': 10,
                    'hidden_dim': 200,
                })

estimator.fit({'training': input_data})
```

I got this success:

```
Epoch: 1, BCELoss: 0.6740543088134454
Epoch: 2, BCELoss: 0.6022386648217026
Epoch: 3, BCELoss: 0.4997656838018067
Epoch: 4, BCELoss: 0.4238818397327345
Epoch: 5, BCELoss: 0.38591035227386317
Epoch: 6, BCELoss: 0.3637635330764615
Epoch: 7, BCELoss: 0.3529281938562588
Epoch: 8, BCELoss: 0.30158030925964824
Epoch: 9, BCELoss: 0.30744082191768957

2021-08-09 00:38:19 Uploading - Uploading generated training modelEpoch: 10, BCELoss: 
0.28836183219539874
2021-08-09 00:38:16,558 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Reporting training SUCCESS

2021-08-09 00:38:39 Completed - Training job completed
ProfilerReport-1628468954: NoIssuesFound
Training seconds: 352
```

Then when I deploy it in the training container with my train.py script which imported your sagemaker_training library, I was able to do it:
predictor = estimator.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
result:
-------------------!

### Then when I tried to batch test using my test dataset in the training container:

```
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-46108efe51ea> in <module>
----> 1 predictions = predict(test_X.values)
  2 predictions = [round(num) for num in predictions]

<ipython-input-133-215b27c43941> in predict(data, rows)
  5     predictions = np.array([])
  6     for array in split_array:
----> 7         predictions = np.append(predictions, predictor.predict(array))
  8 
  9     return predictions

~/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sagemaker/predictor.py in predict(self, data, initial_args, target_model, 
target_variant, inference_id)
134             data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id
135         )
--> 136         response = 
self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
137         return self._handle_response(response)
138 

~/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
384                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
385             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 386             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
387 
388         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
703             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
704             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 705             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
706         else:
707             return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: 
Received server error (0) from model with message "Your invocation timed out while 
waiting for a response from container model. Review the latency metrics for each 
container in Amazon CloudWatch, resolve the issue, and try again.". See https://us-east- 
1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east- 
1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/pytorch-training-2021-08-09-00-47-00-025 
in account 804604702169 for more information.
```

How can void this error? is there anything wrong with updating from "import
sagemaker_container" to "import sagemaker_training"?